# Formatting a table to take a paragraph nicely

Tags: tables, moderncv, tabularx

I am formatting something at the moment and there's a table which is pretty strained. There's a lot of information in it and I think that it would look better in a similar format to the modern CV education sections.

The way that the date is on the left then info is right of that.

Here's an image of that :

[image]

I tried to just copy paste code from the modern CV package but was unable to get it working.

I'm not really bothered about having the exact Modern CV style or anything, and using a table would probably do, but I can't get the layout to work.

here's the code that I currently have :

```
\begin{document}

\def\arraystretch{1.0}
\begin{table}
  % \centering
  \begin{tabular}{p{3cm} p{1cm}}

    \Large{2000-2001} & \textbf{GSH (Gadf Shee Hwer)} Complete Exwww Level 4 \emph{Bahlamuy Avenue, Cirthserr}

  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Which looks like :

[image]

I want the second cell to be a paragraph.

I know I might be asking a lot language wise as I've probably described things awfully, hopefully the desired result isn't too vague though.

### edit

I had a line with the same information outside of the table environment that was confusing me. It's fine now. The suggestion of increasing the cell size worked (i had tried this but didn't think it was working because of the loose line...)

Comment: The second column has a width of just 1 cm, try 6cm.

Comment: What @Johannes_B said. You need to make the cell wider.

Comment: @Johannes_B yes argh I'll edit the OP now it was a very silly error on my part, i tried what you mentioned and didn't *think* it was working as I had a line outside the table with the same information >.<

Comment: also remove the `table` environment.

Comment: use `\Large 2000--2001` not  `\Large{2000-2001} ` (`\Large` does not take an argument so the `{}` there are just confusing, and an ndash not a hyphen for date ranges)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`moderncv` uses the `tabular` environment internally to set those lists. On the other hand, a real list might be better suited for the job. Following three very basic examples, one `tabular` and two lists.

Lists can be altered by packages like `enumitem`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{c p{.6\linewidth}}
    2015-06-08 & a rock and a hard place \\
    2015-06-07 & start me up \\
    2015-06-06 & gimme shelter
\end{tabular}

\begin{description}
    \item [2015] Greta Gabo
    \item [september 2010] \blindtext
\end{description}

\addtokomafont{labelinglabel}{\bfseries}
\begin{labeling}{the longest label}
\item [0] kind of a strange year to be born
\item [2015] presence
\item [2017] future
\item [the longest label] \blindtext
\end{labeling}
\end{document}
```